# Some property doesn't get serialized when returned in a Web API action

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

The issue is with the following class:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Kind}: {Identifier}")]
public class SocialConnection
{
    public virtual Guid UniqueId
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    // SocialConnectionKind is an enumeration
    public virtual SocialConnectionKind Kind { get; set; }

    public virtual string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

`Kind` property never gets serialized: when I request an object which has an associated `SocialConnection` I never get the whole property.

BTW, if I manually call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` it gets serialized. It should be something with the default media-type formatter but I can't figure out the solution so far.

Comment: Please paste the expected and current result, to have more clarity. I have understood, you Json Serialize SocialConnection object and do not receive SocialConnectionKind enum, which otherwise get serialized on JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Comment: @MrinalKamboj You've understood correctly

Comment: @MrinalKamboj BTW I believe the problem is very stupid, I'm about to check the reason behind the issue

Comment: It indeed looks like a very strange issue :)

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I've found what was causing the issue, I'm going to answer myself... you'll laugh a lot ;P

Comment: sure :), keen to figure it out

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I've already added the answer :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue which was causing this serialization problem was very simple. Check `SocialConnectionKind` enumeration:

```
public enum SocialConnectionKind
{
    Skype,
    Facebook,
    Twitter,
    LinkedIn,
    Hangouts
}
```

Did you already notice what could be the problem? The issue wouldn't be reproduced if the value would be any excepting `Skype`!

Why? Enumerations start with `0` and see how I've configured my WebAPI's `HttpConfiguration`:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling =
                                                           DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
```

Which is the default value of the `Enum` default underlying type `int`? Yes, it's `0`.

So, what solved the issue?

```
public enum SocialConnectionKind
{
    Skype = 1, // <--- The issue was solved starting the enumeration from 1!
    Facebook,
    Twitter,
    LinkedIn,
    Hangouts
}
```

### Another approach

As @Avner Shahar-Kashtan have pointed out in some comment, I could also solve this issue using `[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]` attribute:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Kind}: {Identifier}")]
public class SocialConnection
{
    public virtual Guid UniqueId
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = value; }
    }

    // SocialConnectionKind is an enumeration
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]
    public virtual SocialConnectionKind Kind { get; set; }

    public virtual string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

...and this way there's no need of starting an enumeration from `1`.

Anyway, in my particular case, I prefer to stay with the *start from `1`* approach, because I find cleaner avoid polluting my POCOs with serialization-specific attributes because `SocialConnection` class lives in a *shared library* and this serialization issue is an implementation issue in a concrete project.

Comment: Interesting scenario. But wouldn't the *deserializer* have similar settings, and initialize the property to 0/Skype if the value wasn't included? Or is the deserializing code not C#/.NET, so you don't actually have the SocialConnection class there.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Well, in that case, if I'm not mistaken, it would set the value, the whole setting is specific to *serializing*.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Ah, you're right. For now, I'm testing my controllers using C# integration tests (VSTest), BTW, the consumers will be *Web browsers* so it wouldn't receive `0` and, using JavaScript I would need to check if the property `kind` is there. I prefer to avoid this scenario and start from `1`  to avoid that checking. The social connection must have a *kind*.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, but if the net effect of dropping the default value is 0 - that is, both serializer and deserializer can handle it and preserve data integrity - then it's not a *problem* but an implementation detail. A confusing and surprising one, true. :)

Comment: But if your client doesn't use the same deserializer and environment (i.e. javascript) and can't preserve data integrity with missing data (which it can't), then it certainly becomes a problem.
Incidentally, wouldn't it be clearer to simply *not* Ignore default values, rather than changing your enum values?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Do you mean that the whole media-type formatter should be able to be smart enough to check that it's an enumeration and preserve the default value?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan But the issue with *not ignoring* default values is that there're a lot of cases where it's required. If the outgoing DTO has null properties, they shouldn't be serialized with `null` (for example). Since it's a global switch, there's no way of discriminating enumerations from this rule ........

Comment: I agree, but in some cases it might be a trade-off between the required global behavior (which is usually an optimization, but might be a logical switch) and specific behavior (if your enum is already persisted as an integer in the DB, changing the value might not be possible).
Also, you might be able to override it for a given property:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1824580.aspx?Serializing+to+JSON+Nullable+Date+gets+ommitted+using+Json+NET+and+Web+API+despite+specifying+NullValueHandling

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I see (the thing of using the attribute). BTW, isn't cleaner not polluting classes, interfaces and enumerations with serialization-specific attributes? I prefer to keep my code as simple as possible. I won't die if my enumerations aren't started from zero, it's just an implementation detail that it should be documented in both cases

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan About the DB thing, it's a new development so there's no constraint on this... I can change whatever I want :P

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I've added a mention to the other approach you've linked in some comment